# Axios adds extra trailing slash in body values

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, axios, escaping

I am developing an application with React Native, which communicates with an IoT chip (with very little ram memory), because of that all the logic must be developed on the client side.

One of the specifications of this chip is all the characters "," must to be escaped with just one trilling slash.

Ex:

From:

```
{ value: 'foo,bar' }
```

To:

```
{ value: 'foo\,bar' }
```

I am sending this information using axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const body = { value: 'foo,bar' };
const parsedBody = { value: body.value.replace(/,/g, '\\,') } // { value: 'foo\,bar' }

axios({
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  },
  url: 'https://example.com',
  data: body,
}).then(response => {
  console.log('message sent!');
});
```

The problem is that on the other side, the server is receiving the body (as an object) with an extra trilling slash

Ex:

```
{ value: 'foo\\,bar' }
```

I'm not sure if the information is being modified by axios. But I need to receive it with only one trilling slash (I can't parse it on the server side)

Comment: Odds are that you are misinterpreting the result and the function you are using to examine the value is adding an escape character just as a way of representing the string.  We'd need to see the server side code to tell.

Comment: On the front-end: body.value.split(',').join('\,') to convert it to respective format and see the result. Here first converting the string to array based on ',' and then the array is converted to string using '\,'

Comment: @Quentin That was the first thing I thought. But I created a test server to see the results, and the response has an extra character when I check the string length

Comment: @RohitDalal I got the same result with that approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing an object as `data`, I strongly assume that axios uses `JSON.stringify()` to convert that object into a string. The correct JSON representation of the object `{ value: 'foo\\,bar' }` is `{"value":"foo\\,bar"}`, so with the double quotes and the double backslash.

Now I'm not familiar with axios and its documentation doesn't seem to be very detailed, but maybe try passing a string as `data`. Then you have full control over the way it is encoded.

A very simple way to try this would be `data: JSON.stringify(parsedBody).replace(/\\\\,/g, '\\,')`.
This will obviously not work if you ever intentionally want to send `\\,` instead of `\,`. So depending on what kind of data you are planning to send, you might need to implement your own stringification function (for example: `` data: `{ value: '${body.value.replace(/([',\\])/g, '\\$1')}' }` `` )